# node js express file upload is corrupted

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Uploaded files are the same size 16 bytes and corrupted. What am I doing wrong?

looks like the server code is working as it should, most likely a client side issue. But I could be wrong, so I added everything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**server side code:**

```
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

class authController {
downloadFile(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query)
    try {
      const parentFolder = req.query.parentFolder
      const folderId = req.query.folderId
      const fileName = req.query.fileName
      const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
      const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)
      const file = path.join(__dirname, `../files/${parentFolder}/${folderId}/${fileName}`)
      res.download(file, fileName)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong, please try again' })
    }
  }
}

export default new authController()
```

**client side code:**

```
                      onClick={async function (e) {
                        e.stopPropagation()
                        const request = 'downloadFile'
                        const response = await fetch(`/api/auth/${request}?parentFolder=${parentFolder}&folderId=${folderId}&fileName=${item}`, {
                          headers: {
                            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth.token,
                          },
                        })

                        if (response.status === 200) {
                          console.log(response)
                          const blob = response.blob()
                          const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], { type: 'image/png' }))
                          const link = document.createElement('a')
                          link.href = downloadUrl
                          link.download = item
                          document.body.appendChild(link)
                          link.click()
                          link.remove()
                        }
                      }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Replaced

`const blob = response.blob()`

with `const blob = await response.blob()` and everything worked.